# Concatenate javascript variable with html to create href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a href with `html()`, however the output is not correct. What is wrong with this jquery code?

```
$('#tag_modal').find('.modal-body').html("<a href='/companies/explore-companies?tags='"+data.results['tag_id']+">test</a>");
```

Output:

```
<div class="modal-body"><a 5="" href="/companies/explore-companies?tags=">test</a></div>
```

Comment: are you missing a `'` in `">test</a>"` ?

Comment: @Paul it's there, just in wrong place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing the attribute before the tag id, close it after

```
$('#tag_modal').find('.modal-body').html("<a href='/companies/explore-companies?tags="+data.results['tag_id']+"'>test</a>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your quotes are wrong. Try:

```
$('#tag_modal').find('.modal-body')
    .html('<a href="/companies/explore-companies?tags='+data.results['tag_id']+'">test</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your anchor element first:

```
var $anchor = $("<a href='/companies/explore-companies?tags='"+data.results['tag_id']+"'>test</a>");
```

And then appending it to your div:

```
$('#tag_modal').find('.modal-body').append($anchor);
```

That way you're breaking the process into discrete steps (first create the element, second append it to the DOM).

**Edit**: as others have mentioned, you also need to close the href value, with a single quote, before you close the tag with the greater-than symbol.